# What is the polars equivalent of converting a numeric (Year) column to date in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-polars

I am new to `polars` and have been trying to convert just `Year` column to `date` column but failed to do so.

**Data**

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import plotly.express as px

# creating pandas df
df_gapminder = px.data.gapminder()

# creating polars df
pl_gapminder = pl.DataFrame(df_gapminder)
```

**Converting to date column**:

`In pandas`

```
df_gapminder['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_gapminder.year, format="%Y")
df_gapminder.date.head()

############## output ###########
# 0   1952-01-01
# 1   1957-01-01
# 2   1962-01-01
# 3   1967-01-01
# 4   1972-01-01
# Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`In polars` - getting error below

```
pl_gapminder.with_columns(pl.col('year').str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%Y').cast(pl.Date).alias('date'))
```

**Error** SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected `Utf8`, got `i64`

`In Polars` - Getting Wrong Results below

```
pl_gapminder.with_columns(pl.col('year').cast(pl.Date).alias('date')).head()
```

Wrong Output (Instead of increasing `Years` the `days` are increasing in `date` column):

```
country     continent   year    lifeExp pop      gdpPercap  iso_alpha   iso_num   date
str             str     i64      f64    i64        f64          str     i64       date
"Afghanistan"   "Asia"  1952    28.801  8425333     779.445314  "AFG"   4   1975-05-07
"Afghanistan"   "Asia"  1957    30.332  9240934     820.85303   "AFG"   4   1975-05-12
"Afghanistan"   "Asia"  1962    31.997  10267083    853.10071   "AFG"   4   1975-05-17
"Afghanistan"   "Asia"  1967    34.02   11537966    836.197138  "AFG"   4   1975-05-22
"Afghanistan"   "Asia"  1972    36.088  13079460    739.981106  "AFG"   4   1975-05-27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can cast to string, then parse to date (what pandas does for you, under the hood):

```py
pl_gapminder = pl_gapminder.with_columns(
    pl.col('year')
    .cast(pl.Utf8)
    .str.strptime(pl.Date, format='%Y')
    .cast(pl.Date)
    .alias('date')
)

pl_gapminder["date"]
shape: (1704,)
Series: 'date' [date]
[
    1952-01-01
    1957-01-01
    1962-01-01
    1967-01-01
    1972-01-01
    1977-01-01
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `fmt` has since been renamed to `format` so this will fail with more recent versions of `polars`